# How do I search an object full of strings in node js?

Tags: node.js, object

I'm new to node js programming and I have the following :

```
        var myObj = {
          AD: '{+376}',
          AF: '{+93}',
          AG: '{+1268}'
        };
```

NOTE:  I cannot modify this object data, as it comes from a third party component. I have only put an example of what data is returned to me in a local object for debugging purposes.

I'd like to be able to search this object for "AD" and pull out just the +376 from this line

```
"AD": "{+376}"
```

this does not seem to work:

```
        var i = myObj.indexOf("AD");
        console.log(i);
```

***UPDATE***

Sorry... I was using stringify on the object and the output I was seeing in the terminal window was wrong...  I have corrected the question

***UPDATE again***

OK... running it using myObj works in a local sandbox... but using it on the actual data that comes back from the NPM object does not.  Here is a RunKit:

https://npm.runkit.com/country-codes-list

This code does returns the number...

```
var ccl = require("country-codes-list")

var l = ccl.customList('countryCode', '+{countryCallingCode}');
console.log(l.AD);
```

**BUT**  I need a variable instead of .AD like this:

```
var ad = 'AD'
var ccl = require("country-codes-list")

var l = ccl.customList('countryCode', '+{countryCallingCode}');
console.log(l.ad); // doesn't work !
```

Comment: myObj['AD'].slice(1,-1)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5555803/orkhan-alikhanov -  I made a terrible error... see question again. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
var ad = 'AD'
var ccl = require("country-codes-list")

var l = ccl.customList('countryCode', '+{countryCallingCode}');
console.log(l[ad]);
```

Comment: see question... I made a mistake - sorry

Comment: @MLissCetrus not sure why you need that but I have updated the answer. hope this is works for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021796/ashish-modi -  see 'UPDATE AGAIN'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1021796/ashish-modi - please change your answer and I will accept that !  thank you !  thank you !  thank you !

Comment: @MLissCetrus changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key to reach for the value.

```js
var string = '{"AD":"{+376}","AF":"{+93}","AG":"{+1268}"}';
var object = JSON.parse(string);

function search(id) {
  return object[id];
}

console.log(search('AD')) //--> {+376}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/11517388/luispa -  see 'UPDATE AGAIN'